# How to draw a curly brace at a correct location between 2 points with coordinates in a plot?

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-pic

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={x},
    ylabel={y},
    xmin=0, xmax=5,
    ymin=0, ymax=8,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5},
    ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10},
    ]


    \addplot[
    only marks,
    color=blue,
    mark=square
    ]
    coordinates {
        (1,2) (2,4) (3,4) (4,6)
    };

    \addplot[no marks,blue] expression[domain=1:4,samples=50]{1.6*x};

    \end{axis}
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt,mirror}, yshift = -0.2cm]
    (2,4) -- (2,3.2) node (curly_bracket)[black,midway, yshift =- 0.3 cm] 
    {};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to draw a brace between point (2,4) and (2,3.2), but couldn't get it at a correct location using the code

```
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt,mirror}, yshift = -0.2cm]
        (2,4) -- (2,3.2) node (curly_bracket)[black,midway, yshift =- 0.3 cm] 
        {};
```

. You can understand the brace as pointing out the bias of the line when x=2. Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Your `draw` code must in `\begin{axis}` and `\end{axis}`. And your coordinates must define in your coordinate axis, i.e, use `(axis cs:2,4)` instead of `(2,4)` and so on.

Comment: fixed. Thanks! Please move your comment to answer for me to mark it. Thank you!

Comment: You welcome. I added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={x},
    ylabel={y},
    xmin=0, xmax=5,
    ymin=0, ymax=8,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5},
    ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10},
    ]


    \addplot[
    only marks,
    color=blue,
    mark=square
    ]
    coordinates {
        (1,2) (2,4) (3,4) (4,6)
    };
    \addplot[no marks,blue] expression[domain=1:4,samples=50]{1.6*x};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt,mirror}, yshift = -0.2cm]
    (axis cs:2,4) -- (axis cs:2,3.2) node (curly_bracket)[black,midway, yshift =- 0.3 cm] 
    {};
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```